# How can I get a list of all functions stored in the database for all the schemas in db2uw?

Tags: function, db2, db2-luw

I want to know the sql query to find all the functions stored in a db2luw database for all the existing schemas and particularly how can I display the functions of a specific owner.

Comment: Check out the catalog view `SYSCAT.FUNCTIONS` -- it is described in the manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the answer

```
db2 "select ROUTINE_CATALOG, ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_TYPE from sysibm.routines where ROUTINE_NAME='my_function'"
```